# react js localstorage value object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I save what I get from my backend to a local storage:+

```
   async onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const {login, password } = this.state;

        const response = await api.post('/login', { login,password });
        const user = response.data.user;
        const {jwt} = response.data;
        console.log(user);
        localStorage.setItem('token', jwt);
        localStorage.setItem('user', user);
        this.props.history.push("/home");
    }
```

my

> const user = response.data.user;

return this:

```
{id: 2, name: "spt", email: "email", login: "spt", password: "$2a$10$Rqc1VU1TfKD6MypNzbgemeR0O4YeXIFy1XiURjNeHk0gpWJitp4da", …}
```

two object
[object object]

Comment: Can you please clarify what your question is?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Local Storage is key-value storage where key is string and value is string also.

You must stringify your data, you can do this

```
localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
```

And get it like

```
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
```

Comment: Hello i did that what you said and in contact by socket with my backend i sent
    const player = JSON.parse (localStorage.getItem ('user'));


    this.socket.emit ('addPlayer-Queue', player);

Comment: But my backend didn't receive this value, if I change the value to 1 for example my backend gets

Comment: @Felipe socket take string too, you should not do JSON.parse before sending using socket

Comment: Doing this for some reason I don't get this value in the backend

Comment: i need make this: const player = localStorage.getItem('user') ?

Comment: @Felipe you can do next: const user = localStorage.getItem('user'); and send user variable using socket

Comment: I did it now and still not getting backend I believe because of
localStorage.setItem ('user', JSON.stringify (user));

Comment: Can you show me result of console.log(user) after getItem from storage?

Comment: {"id":2,"name":"spt","email":"email","login":"spt","password":"$2a$10$Rqc1VU1TfKD6MypNzbgemeR0O4YeXIFy1XiURjNeHk0gpWJitp4da","mmr":1000,"createdAt":"2019-11-26T17:48:09.861Z","updatedAt":"2019-11-26T17:48:09.861Z"}

Comment: So, all good. How do you submit this data using socket?

Comment: this.socket.emit('addPlayer-Queue', player);

Comment: And on my backend I give console.log my value

Comment: if i set
        localStorage.setItem ('user', user);
 like this
i can get on my backend

[object Object]

but I don't know how I will handle it
i can get on my backend

Comment: @Felipe I don't understand :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203275/discussion-between-saveli-tomac-and-felipe).

Comment: In my back end I can't get any value with this result:

[object Object]?

Answer (score 6):

`localstorage` does not support objects. If you want to store the user in `localstorage`, you need to stringify it: `JSON.stringify(user)`

If you want to store objects, you could use a third-party NPM module like [localforage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localforage) (not supported in all browsers).